# How to get maps data with preg_match?

Tags: php, google-maps, preg-match, preg-match-all

How can i get and echo Google Maps datas with preg_matc function ? I need "data-lat" and "data-lon" values.

Sample Code

```
<div id="gmap" data-lat="41.03406690872433" data-lon="28.67888435619534" data-lang="tr" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">.....</div>
```

I'm tried this code but i dont get any result.

```
<?
$link = 'https://test.com/maps';
$map = '@<div id="gmap">(.*?)</div>@si';

$get = file_get_contents($link);

preg_match_all($map, $getir, $map1);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($map1);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

Result what i need;

```
</div>
      <input type='hidden' name='lat' id="lat" value="<? echo $map[0]; ?>" />//data-lat
      <input type='hidden' name='lng' id="lng" value="<? echo $map[1]; ?>" />//data-lon
      <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 97%; height: 400px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick regular expression solution to extract the lat and lon values with 2 capture groups:
`<div id="gmap".+?data-lat="([\d.]+)".+?data-lon="([\d.]+)".+?<\/div>`

https://regex101.com/r/lhhgBH/1

> Group 1.  25-42   `41.03406690872433`
>
> Group 2.  54-71   `28.67888435619534`

If you help using that reg ex check the PHP [preg_match documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

Full example

```
$map = '@<div id="gmap".+?data-lat="([\d.]+)".+?data-lon="([\d.]+)".+?<\/div>@si';
$getir = '<div id="gmap" data-lat="41.03406690872433" data-lon="28.67888435619534" data-lang="tr" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden;">.....</div>';

preg_match_all($map, $getir, $map1);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($map1);
echo "</pre>";
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
.....

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 41.03406690872433
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 28.67888435619534
        )

)
```

So you see the values you need, to get them just use `$map1[1][0]` (lat) and `$map1[2][0]` (lon).

Comment: So, new code is this?
$map= '@<div id="gmap".+?data-lat="([\d.]+)".+?data-lon="([\d.]+)".+?<\/div>(.*?)</div>@si';

Comment: That is just the reg ex to extract your search, but in general yes that's most of it. You just need to get the two capture groups. You can show a little effort and implement that yourself in php, if you don't know how read the php link I've provided. :)

Comment: I'm newbie and first time using preg_match method. I spended for this 3-4 hours but i can't solved. Thank you for your help by the way. But I do not know how to do it. :)

Comment: Well in your question you already have `print_r($map1);`, so when you use my new regex just look at what is printed, it should contain the lat and lon values somewhere in the output.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 

)

with this code: $map= '@<div id="gmap".+?data-lat="([\d.]+)".+?data-lon="([\d.]+)".+?<\/div>@si';

Comment: Updated my answer and added a full example, I think it is clearer now? As a side note I prefer `var_dump` to `print_r`, it shows more relevant data when debugging.

Comment: Thank you so much i'm solved with this code. Thank you again :)